# Failed to Enable Constraints Errors after moving Database and Driver

Tags: mysql, database, text, sqldatatypes

I am moving a fairly large system over to a new server and new MySQL database.

The system has been running for a few years on MySQL using ODBC data drivers, I am now using MySQL drivers and have started running into a problem.

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

A bit of Googling brought me to this article:

[http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2004/10/03/DataSet-hell-*2D00*-_2200_Failed-to-enable-constraints.-One-or-more-rows--contain-values_2E002E002E002E002200_.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2004/10/03/DataSet-hell-_2D00_-_2200_Failed-to-enable-constraints.-One-or-more-rows--contain-values_2E002E002E002E002200_.aspx)

Having read through that a few others including the MySQL docs I have identified the problem to being some `text` fields in my database which have quite large content.

I traced one instance of the problem to an individual record, amended the data in one of the `text` fields so it was shorter and it removed the problem.

Having put the content into MS Word, the character count is 30,000, running `LENGTH(report)` (report is the field name) in a Query on phpMyAdmin (which will happily show all the rows) agrees, it shows a length of 33108

So, this must be where the problem is, but surely I can handle this kind of data?

I'm not sure where the problem is though, is it the new database setup, or the use of the MySQL Drivers?

I am trying to use the data as a `DataTable` as follows:

```
Public Shared Function getTable() as DataTable
    Dim connection As MySqlConnection = Common.getConnection()        
    connection.Open()
    Dim connect As MySqlCommand = Common.createCommand(sql, connection)
    Dim getData As New DataTable()
    getData.Load(connect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    return getData
End Function

Public Shared Function getConnection() As MySqlConnection
    Dim DBConnection As String
    DBConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConn").ConnectionString
    Dim oConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(DBConnection) 
    getConnection = New MySqlConnection(DBConnection)
End Function

Public Shared Function createCommand(sql As String, connection As MySqlConnection) As MySqlCommand
    createCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
End Function
```

(Previously I was using `OdBcCommand` and  `OdBcConnection`s and it all worked!)

I am not sure where to go from here, without filtering through all my data, which I don't want to have to do, and removing all long fields I am unsure how to fix this problem?

Any advice much appreciated!

============

UPDATE IN CASE IT HELPS ANYONE ELSE, FROM THE ACCEPTED ANSWER (thanks very much):

changing my code:

```
    Dim getData As New DataTable()
    getData.Load(connect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
```

To:

```
    Dim dataset As New DataSet()
    Dim getData As New DataTable()
    dataset.Tables.Add(getData)
    getData.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = False
    getData.Load(connect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
```

Removed the issue, now long fields work fine.

Comment: Are the values in the text fields that are very long still active/needed records?

Comment: @ryan1234 yes I am afraid they are needed. There are very few out of thousands of rows, but those that are long are required. I have updated the question with the solution from the accepted answer in case it can help anyone in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few solutions i found.

- Clear the Dataset / DataTable and rebind bindings. Continue reading [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/00698a44-8fd6-4f04-b168-5842b52487a6/#b17da25c-831d-48ae-8756-bbd27f9dbf86).
- Either not calling FillSchema or disabling constraint checking on the Datatable. Continue reading [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36364).
- Set EnforceConstraints to false and load data after that.

  ```
  Dim getData As New DataTable()
  getData.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;
  getData.Load(connect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
  return getData
  ```

  Continue reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35.aspx).

Comment: Hi @Jamie Hartnoll please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Awesome :D Sorry took a while to get back to it. Your third option and code worked, I wasn't declaring any `DataSet` object specifically but now using this: `Dim dataset As New DataSet
Dim getData As New DataTable()
dataset.Tables.Add(getData)            getData.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = False            getData.Load(connect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))` it works!

Comment: I have added your code to my question in case it can be of help to anyone else, thanks again